# Google login integration in Fragment not working .enableAutoManage(this, this)

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, google-signin

Hi I am integrating google login in fragment i am following this one

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

,now issue is that

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

here i am not able to access .enableAutoManage(this, this) ..
what should i add insted of (this,this)

Comment: then where can i add that gso?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api